# cargar páginas externas en mi web sin afectar el nombre del dominio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quiero que todas las páginas web externas se carguen dentro de mi web y sin que afecte la dirección original de mi página, hay algun método? sin usar 'embed' y el otro que no recuerdo... quiero que todo sea automático.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has buscado o intentado hasta ahora? Por favor revisa [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

creo que una etiqueta [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) de HTML podrías cargar todos los contenido externos de una web, sin que afecte a tu dominio. Si especificas un poco mejor, seguro que podemos echarte una mano. ;)